# Why does a subtraction from clientX break a JS event handler?

Tags: javascript

Taking a web programming class. We had an exercise to take an image drag it around and release. But we hit a mystery.

This code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script> 

// Mouse move event handler
function move(e)
{
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById( "picture" );

    var left = e.clientX-50;
    var top = e.clientY-50;

    x.setAttribute( "style", "top: " + top + "px; left: " + left + "px;");
}
// End function move()

// Mouse click event handler
function grab(e)
{
    document.addEventListener( "mousemove", move, false);

}
// End function grab()

// Mouse click release event handler
function drop(e)
{
    document.removeEventListener( "mousemove", move, false);

}
// End function drop()

    document.addEventListener( "mousedown", grab, false);
    document.addEventListener( "mouseup", drop, false);
</script>

<style> 

#picture
{position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1> 
<img id='picture' src='ugly.jpg'> </h1>


</body>
</html>
```

This is not my code (the image moves if you click anywhere on the document). The thing that got us all mystified is

```
var left = e.clientX-50;
var top = e.clientY-50;
```

does not work at all while

```
var left = e.clientX;
var top = e.clientY;
```

sorta works with the cursor right on the tip of the image. I used a horrible nested set of eventhandler functions and used the -50 with no probs at all.

How the heck can subtracting 50 from clientX completely change the behavior of the handler?

Grateful for any thoughts. Thanks in advance

Steve

PS My code was:

```
var myleft = e.clientX - 50;
var mytop = e.clientY - 50;
var mystyle = "left:" + myleft + "px; top:" + mytop + "px";
bigImage.setAttribute("style", mystyle);
```

which worked fine.

Comment: Works fine for me, with and without the `-50`. Maybe you can define a bit more what you mean by "does not work at all". And possibly whether you get an error messages in the console.

Comment: Sorry for delay.


@christian For some reason you really need a Ctrl F5 to refresh this page in Chrome. 

With - 50px, when you mouse down and try and drag you get typical ghost image When you mouse up it THEN engages mousemove and the imge follows the cursor around the page until you click (not mousedown) which releases the image. Without the -50s when you mousedown it drags with you and mouseup releases it. Only 2 probs. 1) Because no -50 -50 the cursor is right at the top corner of the image. 2) a doc.addevent instead of node.addevent is used then a mousdown ANYWHERE on doc starts the move.